# Check currently installed Notepad++ version in Powershell

Tags: notepad++, silent-installer

I need to know the currently installed Notepad++ version for an auto update script. Does anybody know how I can get it within Powershell? Maybe there is a registry entry?

Answer (score 1):

The following command `(Get-Item "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion` returns `7.88`

That should probably be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to @Mohammed Shabeer kp answer and combine this with my gist to silently install Notepad++ on your systems. I'll work on adding the the registry query to the script to check if Notepad++ is installed first. This way we dont download unnecessary files.

[Install-NotepadPlusPlus.ps1](https://gist.github.com/cjerrington/bc95d40750c04680d814dc42fda2b6c6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-ItemProperty` to get the whole properties and then output the version
from the property list. Hope the below helps.

```
$w64=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | where-Object DisplayName -like 'NotePad++*'
$w32=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | where-Object DisplayName -like 'NotePad++*'

if ($w64) {
     write-Host $w64.DisplayVersion 
} elseif ($w32) {
     write-Host $w32.DisplayVersion
} else {
     Write-Output "No Version Found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10, you can right-click it and select properties and click on details. You can find the current version of any application

Comment: You should reread the question, they need version for an auto update script.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting version info from .exe file**
Please note that while this command: `(Get-Item "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion` suggested above by Caleb DOES work, it seems like at least for some older versions of Notepad++ there is a little bug. I happened to try out this command with Notepad version 8.3.2 and it gave me the output of 8.32 (instead of 8.3.2). The implication is, of course, that when doing a version comparison, your result will be incorrect in many cases (e.g. when comparing 8.6.2 with 8.32, the latter is greater, whereas when comparing 8.6.2 with the correct 8.3.2, the former is greater).

**Getting version info from registry**
So I checked the registry, which seems more reliable here:
As of the point of writing this (February 2024), there is a fixed registry path for both 32-bit and 64-bit version of Notepad++ where you can find the currently installed version of this software:

32-bit:
 "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++" --> Property "DisplayVersion"
64-bit:
"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++" --> Property DisplayVersion

You can directly read this out using PowerShell (no need for an elevated prompt) with the following Code (example is the 64-bit version, just adapt the path for 32-bit):

```
(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++").DisplayVersion
```

If you need this not as a string, but as a version-Object (e.g. for comparing an installed version with the currently available version), simply convert the string to a version-Object like this:

```
[version](Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++").DisplayVersion
```